# kubectl delete/create secret forbidden (Google cloud platform)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I was following the following tutorial on continuous integration using gitlab and Kubernetes (in my case on google cloud): https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/.

At some point in the tutorial you will have to first delete and then create a secret for the image registry of Gitlab:

```
- kubectl delete secret registry.gitlab.com
- kubectl create secret docker-registry registry.gitlab.com --docker-server=https://registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=$REGISTRY_USERNAME --docker-password=$REGISTRY_PASSWD --docker-email=$EMAIL
```

Things go wrong in this step, I get the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "registry.gitlab.com" is forbidden: User "client" cannot delete secrets in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets is forbidden: User "client" cannot create secrets in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"
```

I get the same exact error in the Google cloud shell:

[image]

Adding the following line does not really help, I still get the creation error (I am also 100% sure that the deletion also 'crashes' but the '2>/dev/null' just makes it move to the creation step):

```
kubectl delete secret registry.gitlab.com 2>/dev/null || echo "secret does not exist"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RUN `gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate`

After this logout and login. It should work. This happens when you disable Legacy Authorisation in the cluster settings, because the client certificate that you are using is a legacy authentication method

Comment: That was my comment in the tutorial, If I add that line is doesn't crash on the deletion but it does on the creation of the secret: 'Error from server (Forbidden): secrets is forbidden: User "client" cannot create secrets in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"'

Comment: What type of account are you using to perform these actions? Are you using a service account.

Comment: I created a 'Compute Engine default service account' as shown in the tutorial. The weird thing is that in an older git repo the creation and deletion of secrets worked. I recreated my git repo (maven --> gradle) and now I get this situation.

Comment: Do this. NOT for production level codes. As this would give admin access to the said service account.

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin--clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts` 

This would make sure you have the access to create secretes.

Comment: I get 'error: clusterrole must be specified'. What should I set clusterrole to?

Comment: @Jdruwe there is a space missing. Try: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts`