# Kubernetes Continuous deployment stage in Gitlab Online fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, kubectl

I am working on setting up a cloud DevOps deployment pipeline using Gitlab CI online, Kubernetes, and docker. I am following an example post at [Continous delivery of a spring boot application with Gitlab CI and kubernetes](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/) and [Kubectl delete/create secret forbidden (Google cloud platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015081/kubectl-delete-create-secret-forbidden-google-cloud-platform) .

Find below my .gitlab-ci.yml file's source

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer .
  - docker push registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer

k8s-deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "$GOOGLE_KEY" > key.json
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
  - gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-c
  - gcloud config set project mta-hosting-optimizer
  - gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate
  - gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials mta-hosting-optimizer
  - kubectl create -f admin.yaml --validate=false
  - kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin--clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts
  - kubectl delete secret registry.gitlab.com
  - kubectl create secret docker-registry registry.gitlab.com --docker-server=https://registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=username --docker-password=$REGISTRY_PASSWD --docker-email=email@email.com
  - kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

Deployment fails at the line below

```
  - kubectl create -f admin.yaml --validate=false
```

The error message displayed upon this failure is as follow:

```
error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The admin.yaml file's source is as follows:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 kind: ClusterRoleBinding metadata: name: kubernetes-dashboard labels: k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard roleRef: apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io kind: ClusterRole name: cluster-admin subjects: - kind: ServiceAccount name: kubernetes-dashboard namespace: kube-system
```

The Maven build and Docker build/package stages work find. This is the only stage that fails. I will appreciate everyone's help in resolving this issue.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using? Could you reformat your admin.yaml file content in question, because spaces and new lines are important for the YAML format?

Comment: Also, using `--validate=false` will **rarely** end well

Answer (score 1):

You have a YAML validation error. This means that your YAML isn't formatted correctly.

[image: screenshot]

You most likely wanted to format your `admin.yaml` file this way:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 
kind: ClusterRoleBinding 
metadata: 
    name: kubernetes-dashboard 
    labels: 
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef: 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io 
  kind: ClusterRole 
  name: cluster-admin 
subjects: 
- kind: ServiceAccount 
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
```

---

**Also:** As Matthew L Daniel already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236932/kubernetes-continuous-deployment-stage-in-gitlab-online-fails#comment89494969_51236932) you shouldn't disable validation of the YAML files.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bn4t. I will apply this as you have formatted and communicate the outcome later. I did not disable validation initially but after I kept getting errors upon errors and saw someone's recommendation to do so.

Comment: thanks for the help, however I get the following error: Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "registry.gitlab.com" is forbidden: User "client" cannot delete secrets in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets is forbidden: User "client" cannot create secrets in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"

Comment: Seems like you're trying to apply this yaml using an account that doesn't seems to exist (and therefore doesn't has the correct permissions). You'll have to look into the Kubernetes documentation on how to manage authorization (e.g. here using RBAC: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/ ).